# Springboot Reactive findByusername return "monomap" by r2dbc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive, r2dbc

I am writing the reactive springboot with mysql and r2dbc.When i writing the query with findByUsername, it just return a String "monotype" instead of an object.

Code:

```
@Override
    public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {

            log.info("get user");
        System.out.println(userRespository.findByUsername(username));  //print "monoNext" in the console
              Mono<UserDetails> ans=  userRespository.findByUsername(username).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException())).map(
                      SecurityUser::new
              );

              return ans;
```

My respository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRespository extends R2dbcRepository<User,Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = :username ;")
    Mono<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

ANyone have idea for it?

Comment: what you expect here? you're just printing Mono.toString() here, what is the issue?

Comment: I am expecting to print the item inside the User object,but i have no idea on how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you actually print `Mono.toString()` because repository returns `Mono`

To print `User` when it is found you should put a callback to your reactive chain, using, for example, [doOnNext()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) operator

```
return userRespository.findByUsername(username)
                // put this callback means "when user is found, print whatever you want here"
                .doOnNext(user -> System.out.println(user))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                .map(SecurityUser::new);
```